# How to use non-key composite elements in EJB3?

Tags: persistence, ejb-3.0, entity

Using EJB3/JBoss, how can I use a composite element from a table, e.g.

```
@Entity
public class X {
   @Id
   private int id;
   private Coordinate coordinate;
}
```

where `Coordinate` is a defined as (setters/getters left out for readability):

```
public class Coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

And everything should be mapped to Table `X` which contains columns `id`, `x`, `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the @Embedded and @Embeddable annotations.